# granularity of views filter on date field

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type which has a date field. That date field collects:

- Year
- Month
- Day
- Hour
- Minute

I've created a view with a filter on that field. The granularity I can filter with only goes down to day. Even if I use `operator: is greater than` and `Relative date: now`, the contents of the view only change once a day. That means that hour and minute are not taken into consideration.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I just did a quick check with a view and a date field, it was no problem to set the granularity on the filter down to seconds. Maybe something wrong with your content type?

Comment: @volker: You where right. My CT was messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Double check your field is collecting the correct date attributes.
2) Make sure "Date Views" is enabled under Modules (Requires: Date API, Views, Chaos tools).

If the above are okay then try creating a new date field making sure you're collecting all date attributes. This should rule out any issues there might be with the field. It could also pay to try create a new date field in a different content type and see how views reacts.

If the new date field doesn't work and views still can't filter down to seconds granularity then try a new test view.

Tested with no problems on Drupal 7.18, Date 7.x-2.6 and Views 7.x-3.5.

Comment: You are right. There is something wrong with my content type since I've previously changed the granularity of that field via manually editing the `features` file and reverting. This is obviously the reaason for that behavior.

Comment: Actually the view filter had the previous granularity. Changing it from the settings solved this problem.